# Accessing the host names in the ansible_hosts file in a loop in Ansbile ?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, ansible

I'm trying to automate [zookeeper install](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkMulitServerSetup) using Ansible. I want to add a bunch of lines to my `cfg` file. Following is an example where there are 5 nodes. `zoo1`, `zoo2`, `zoo3` etc the hosts that I've in my `ansible_hosts` file.

I want to implement it out with `with_items` but cannot figure it out. Any idea how to access the host name in the `ansible_hosts` file in a loop ?

```
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=zoo1:2888:3888
server.2=zoo2:2888:3888
server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
server.4=zoo4:2888:3888
server.5=zoo5:2888:3888
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [lineinfile](http://docs.ansible.com/lineinfile_module.html) module `with_items: groups['<GROUP_NAME>']` (or `with_items: groups['all']` if you want to reference all of the defined hosts).

Comment: That is right. Check out more info about that in the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts)

Answer (score 0):

you can automate this by doing a loop in template

`{% for host in groups['06'] %}
server.{{ loop.index }}={{ hostvars[host]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}:2888:3888
{% endfor %}`